# Assigning numerical values to a Survey in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a questionnaire with radio buttons and checkboxes which I want to grade. Almost all of them have this format:

```
 <input type="radio" name="1" value="Да" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('pls').setAttribute('required', true)" required>Да 
 <input type="radio" name="1" value="Не" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('pls').removeAttribute('required')">Не </br>
```

I need both the name and value attributes to carry their current purpose, so I cannot use them.

Is there a way to still assign some point values to the different answers and get they summed client side. Then ill add them as a different column in a database. The problem is just having an attribute carry the value of the answer.

EDIT: 
This is the full format of 2 questions:

```
 <b>1.QUESTION?</b></br> 
  <input type="radio" name="1" value="Да" data-points="1" onclick="document.getElementById('pls').setAttribute('required', true)" required>Да  
   <input type="radio" name="1" value="Не" data-points="0" onclick="document.getElementById('pls').removeAttribute('required')">Не </br>
   <input type="radio" name="1" value="Пропуснах да се огледам" onclick="document.getElementById('pls').removeAttribute('required')">Пропуснах да се огледам </br>
      <i>COMENT?</i> </br>
     <textarea name="edno" id="pls"></textarea></br>
   </br>
   <b>2.QUESTION?</b></br> 
   <input type="radio" name="2" value="Да" data-points="1" onclick="document.getElementById('2a').removeAttribute('required')" required>Да  
    <input type="radio" name="2" value="Не" data-points="0" onclick="document.getElementById('2a').setAttribute('required', true)">Не     </br>
     <i>COMMENT</i> </br>
    <textarea id="2a" name="dve"></textarea></br></br>
```

Now I need when I have option one ДА  checked to add 1 point and when НЕ is checked to add 0 points to the score. I hope this clears it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, could you clarify it?

Comment: I need to have a variable to carry grade values for each checked answer. I cannot use the name and value attributes, and i do not think that there are any other available, or at least I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

```
<input type="radio" name="1" value="Да" data-points="10" onclick="changePoints(this); document.getElementById('pls').setAttribute('required', true)" required>Да 
<input type="radio" name="1" value="Не" data-points="5" onclick="changePoints(this); document.getElementById('pls').removeAttribute('required')">Не
```

So you can get them with javascript:

```
function changePoints(el)
{
    var points = el.dataset.points;
    alert(points);
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7pjsrz4b/)

Remember: For any kind of data you need to set in an element, use `data-` attributes. Is not nice to use any other default attribute for that.

Comment: Does the el.dataset.points automatically sum the values of all data-points which have been checked or do i need to come up with a formula or a counter for that to work?

Comment: @KaloyanDimov you'll have to do it by yourself. You can use `document.querySelectorAll('[data-points]')` to get all elements with `data-points` attribute, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/7pjsrz4b/1/

Comment: Got it I think it works. Thank you so much. Accepting.

Comment: Nah.. it is not actually working as i thought it would. This gives me the number of questions with datapoint attributes it does not return the actual points assigned to the different answers. I tried to run the function both on each answer select and on page submit.

Comment: @KaloyanDimov your question is about to get an specific attribute from the element. I suggest you to create another question regarding that problem with answers and stuff. Then you add more information about your question/answer structure.

Comment: but it is still the same question why would i ask another one? I need to have points assigned to each answer of a question and then process them. It is still the same thing.. or I think so

Comment: @KaloyanDimov so add more information. Your radios are questions? It doesn't seems so. Questions' html structure would be helpful

Comment: Just the jsfiddle doesnt seem to work. I removed the second close tag of the div but still displays nothing. I get what you are doing but I am not sure if the problem is in the loops or just the displaying of the result. Should i assign the function to a submit button? but as i see it has event listener which should execute the calculation on click so I guess it is not that. Sorry that i am not getting it :(.

Comment: Found it .. having id score and var score wasnt getting along together Fixed it think this will do THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Ok aparently the world hates me. In JSfiddle works when i copy it to my documents it doesnt. Tried it on a blank document with just the code and it still doesnt work. Added Script Type javascript and what not still refuses xD

Comment: @KaloyanDimov note that in the js settings in jsfiddle the code is set to run at *onload*  event, which means that you need to wrap your code in the an `window.onload = function() { ... }`

Comment: I was looking at the additional info on the Javascript part of the fiddle but i though it was default and yes this fixed it again. Thank you and i hope i wont bother you anymore.

Comment: @KaloyanDimov np, those settings are kinda tricky, you're not the first I've seem confused with it.